# Unable To Insert Record FireBase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I just want to insert data on User table inside firebase for this I have created collection of tables, here is the screenshot

**Collection**

[image]

and using this to refer the location of table

```
 final DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference("sharelocation-c7f0f/database/firestore/data~2FUsers~2Fz5hgLqzkdOKKctKpmyex");
```

and this is the code to save the user

**Save User**

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                                LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                                HashMap<String,String> user =new HashMap<>();
                                user.put("Name","fake");
                                user.put("Email","fake@test.coom");
                                user.put("Device",android.os.Build.MODEL);
                                user.put("Phone", String.valueOf( "32254523"));
                                user.put("RegisterOn",dtf.format(now));

                                user.put("isActive",String.valueOf("true"));

                                user.put("isLogin",String.valueOf("true"));

                                databaseReference.setValue(user);

                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

please let me know if I am missing something as I am new at firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot is showing data in Cloud Firestore, but your code is using the SDK for Firebase Realtime Database.  These databases are completely separate from each other.  If you want to use Firestore, you should follow the [documentation for working with it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) instead.